# How to format salesforce data field value to dd mmm

Tags: apex

I have a date field on a custom object which I need to format to format dd mmmm

I used debug and it returns date as : 2018-08-30 00:00:00
I want to format this to 30 Aug.

I tried using the format method but nothing seems to be working.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: mind updating your post with what and how you did try? there are alot of date formating questions on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are formatting in **Apex** use something like

```
Datetime myDT = Datetime.now();  
String myDate = myDT.format('dd MMM yyyy h:mm a'); 
System.debug(myDate);
```

For more formats [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-simpledateformat)
**If in Visual force page,**

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yy}">
    <apex:param> value="{!myDT}" />
</apex:outputText>
```